# Zend Framework: Calling function from a different file

Tags: php, zend-framework, function, instance

****Edit2: Core.php was not found because Bootstrap.php needed Core.php included
    require_once 'C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\application\Core\Core.php';
Solved my Problem ****

---

I am using zendframework and i created a new folder with file Core/Core.php for my functions that i will use in my controllers and elsewhere. But when i try to test a function in my Core.php nothing will show up. I think i am calling the core.php incorrectly but im not sure what the error is.

application/controllers/

IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

     public function init()
    {
         $this->tournamentAction();
    }

   public function indexAction(){          

   }

    public function tournamentAction()
  {            
        $bleh = new Core();
        $this->view->ha = $bleh->yo();
        $this->renderScript('tournament/index.phtml');            
    }    
}
```

application/Core/

Core.php

```
class Core{

    public function init(){

    }

    public function indexAction(){

    }
    public function yo(){
        $text = 'This is my function Yo';
        return $text;
    }
```

application/views/scripts/tournament/
index.phtml

```
$this->ha;
echo "hello";
```

**Edit: Error reporting is nice ha! This is the error i get.**

```
 ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Core' not found in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 19
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  678944  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0275  3090632 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:26
3   0.0275  3090632 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0275  3090728 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.0446  4801056 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.0456  4823424 Zend_Controller_Action->__construct( )  ..\Standard.php:268
7   0.0547  5211576 IndexController->init( )    ..\Action.php:133
8   0.0547  5211576 IndexController->tournamentAction( )    ..\IndexController.php:8
```

Comment: You never `echo` or `print` the `$this->ha`.

Comment: I just made that change but it still did not print anything.

Comment: Does it get printed when you do: `echo $this->ha; die;`?

Comment: No it does not display anything for echo or print_r

Comment: Please tick the correct answer if any help has been given by one of these.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that the autoloader can't find your Core class.

Usually I structure my application by using a library folder where all my models and tools end.

In your case, I would create in the library folder a folder called MyProject, inside it you can put your Core.php class, put you'll have to correct it's name which leads to :

library/MyProject/Core.php

```
class MyProject_Core{

public function init(){

}

public function indexAction(){

}
public function yo(){
    $text = 'This is my function Yo';
    return $text;
}
```

Of course you'd to call your class this way:

```
$coreInstance = new MyProject_Core();
```

Put this function in your application/Bootstrap.php :

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('MyProject_');
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Then the Zend_Loader should find your class whithout any problem.

Comment: +1 for specific tools/logic in the library folder and the autoloader, but I think models should stay within the models or module/models folder

Comment: Yes, I admit this is a personnal choice that could be discussed but I often consider my model as library part since they doesn't often direct end user action.

Answer (score 0):

In your `view` you do:

```
$this->ha; // this doesn't do anything without an echo / print
```

Also you said:

> I think i am calling the core.php incorrectly but im not sure what the error is.

If that's the case you should enable error reporting.

Add this at the top of your bootstrap file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Haha thanks the error reporting will help nicely. I edited my question to the output of the error. It seems it cannot find my Core.php class. Am i calling it incorrectly or do i need to change settings for it to be seen? Thanks for your help